# Convert point to LatLng on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to get the right location of my point on the map as Latlng:

```
let point = L.point(0,0) // x=0,y=0
let latlng = map.unproject(point)
```

but the `latlng` value is not the real location!

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the function: `unproject` is not correct.

you should use: `layerPointToLatLng`:

```
let point = L.point(0,0); // x=0,y=0
let latlng = map.layerPointToLatLng(point);
```

regards

Rachel